# Multiplying matrix polynomials in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm trying to perform matrix polynomial multiplication of the type:

`(A_1+A_2*y)*(B_1+B_2*y+B_3*y^2)`

where `y` is the variable, all the `A_i` are constant matrices of the same size and all the `B_i` are constant matrices of the same size, and the matrix multiplication of the form `A_i*B_i` makes sense. The matrices `A_i` and `B_i` are known and specified by the user.

Formally the multiplication should result in `C_1+C_2*y+C_3*y^2+C_4*y^3` and I would like to know the `C_i`. In MATLAB, if the `A_i` and `B_i` are scalars, one could use 'conv'. However, if they are not scalars, the problem is not as easy. I would like to know if there is a simple way (analogous to 'conv') of doing this with matrices in MATLAB: given the `A_i` and `B_i` I would like to know the `C_i`? Of course, I'd like this in a general sense (univariate matrix polynomials of any degree), and would highly want to avoid using the symbolic toolbox.

Comment: I though I understood your question, but in fact is not quite clear. What do you want to do with the matrices A_1, A_2 and so on? Do you want them to be scalars? Subreferences from a matrix? What have you tried?

Comment: @Werner Yes, an example would have been illuminating. What he wants is an equivalent to the scalar conv, an example: `a = [1,1]; % <-> 1+1x`, `b = [1,1]; % <-> 1+1x`, `c = conv(a,b); % = [1,2,1] <-> (1+1x)*(1+1x) = 1+2x+1x^2`. Take a look at the end of my "Test by" code to understand what he is talking about :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not the best solution, but you could reimplement `conv` for matrices, e.g.:

```
function C = convMat(A,B)
    nA = size(A,3);
    nB = size(B,3);
    n = nA + nB - 1;
    C = zeros([size(A,1),size(B,2),n]);
    for k = 1:n
        for j = max(1,k+1-nB):min(k,nA)
            C(:,:,k) = C(:,:,k) + A(:,:,j)*B(:,:,k-j+1);
        end
    end
```

For your interest: Another (worse?) implementation:

```
function C = convMat2(A,B)
    n = size(A,3) + size(B,3) - 1;
    C = zeros([size(A,1),size(B,2),n]);
    for mA = 1:size(A,1)
        for mB = 1:size(B,2)
            for l = 1:size(A,2) % = size(B,1)
                vA = A(mA,l,:);
                vA = vA(:);
                vB = B(l,mB,:);
                vB = vB(:);
                C(mA,mB,:) = C(mA,mB,:) + reshape(conv(vA,vB),[1,1,n]);
            end
        end
    end
```

Test by:

```
% matrix example
A(:,:,1) = rand(3,3); % A1
A(:,:,2) = rand(3,3); % A2
B(:,:,1) = rand(3,4); % B1
B(:,:,2) = rand(3,4); % B2
B(:,:,3) = rand(3,4); % B3

C1 = convMat(A,B);
C2 = convMat2(A,B);

% test
x = rand(1,1);
(A(:,:,1) + A(:,:,2)*x) * (B(:,:,1) + B(:,:,2)*x + B(:,:,3)*x^2)
C1(:,:,1) + C1(:,:,2)*x + C1(:,:,3)*x^2 + C1(:,:,4)*x^3
C2(:,:,1) + C2(:,:,2)*x + C2(:,:,3)*x^2 + C2(:,:,4)*x^3
```

I am sure it is possible to optimize `convMat`.

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough, using my [sympoly](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9577-symbolic-polynomial-manipulation) toolbox, found on the file exchange. (Does the fact that this avoids the symbolic TB, while using my own sympoly TB invalidate the answer? Only you can decide that.) I'll give an example, with the matrices being fairly non-creatively built.

```
sympoly y

A_1 = rand(2);
A_2 = rand(2);
B_1 = rand(2);
B_2 = rand(2);
B_3 = rand(2);
```

The result is a 2x2 matrix of symbolic polynomial elements, since addition, multiplication and matrix multiplication are all defined for the sympoly class.

```
(A_1+A_2*y)*(B_1+B_2*y+B_3*y^2)
ans =
Sympoly array has size = [2  2]

Sympoly array element [1  1]
    0.88896 + 0.88074*y + 0.87653*y^2 + 0.33102*y^3
Sympoly array element [2  1]
    0.87079 + 1.2145*y + 1.0628*y^2 + 0.69004*y^3
Sympoly array element [1  2]
    0.64143 + 0.78816*y + 0.67242*y^2 + 0.2091*y^3
Sympoly array element [2  2]
    0.64582 + 1.0162*y + 0.78167*y^2 + 0.4313*y^3
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried it too, but found the solution by @matheburg more practical for my purposes.